# Right outer join in linq to entities query

Tags: c#, join, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

Each `Order` make in some `RoutingStep`s, each step contains an `Operation` and each operation do in a `Workshop`.

```
public class Order
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string OrderNumber {get; set;}
   public virtual collection<Routing> Routings{get; set;}
}
public class Routing
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
   public virtual Operation Operation{get; set;}
}
public class Operation
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Workshop Workshop{get; set;}
}
public class Workshop
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

I want to write a linq to entity query(method syntax) to know each order pass which `Workshop`s and doesn't pass which `Workshop`s. In the other word
if I have 4 `Workshop`s totally and `O1` contains 3 `Routing` steps, I want following result for `O1`:

```
------------------------------
| Order  |  Workshop | status |
------------------------------
|   O1   |   W1      |  pass  |
------------------------------
|   O1   |   W2      |  pass  |
------------------------------
|   O1   |   W3      |not pass|
------------------------------
|   O1   |   W4      |  pass  |
-------------------------------
```

I write following code

```
var query = db.Orders
    .SelectMany(order=> order.Routings
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Number = g.Order.OrderNumber,
        Workshop = g.Operation.Workshop.Title,
        Status = g.????
    }).ToList();
```

Which code should I use instead "???" ?

Comment: @developer033 : `Status` isn't a field, I used it just for column header name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = db.Orders
    .SelectMany(x => db.Workshops, (x, y) => new { Order = x, Workshop = y }) // all combinations of orders with workshops
    .GroupJoin( // left join to determine whether each combination actually exists
        db.Routings,
        x => x,  // proposed order-workshop pair
        y => new { Order = y.Order, Workshop = y.Operation.Workshop }, // existing order-workshop pair
        (x, ys) => new
        {
            x.Order.OrderNumber,
            x.Workshop.Title,
            Status = ys.Any() ? "pass" : "not pass"
        });
```

Comment: So, what is `x => workshops` in 2nd line? `Order` does not have `workshops` directly.

Comment: @Masoud, Added some more comments. Does that help explain?